# How to express in RDF(S)/OWL that two entities are somehow related?

Tags: rdf, owl, abstraction, reasoning

I would like to express in RDF that two entities ex:e1 and ex:e2 are somehow related via some property. Unfortunately, blank nodes are not allowed in property position. In OWL there is owl:topProperty, but its extension contains all combinations of entities, thus this is not what I need.

Of course I could define a property on my own: ex:e1 ex:relatedTo ex:e2, but is there another way?

This would help me to "abstract" RDF graphs. After abstracting the graph we would only know that ex:e1 and ex:e2 are related without knowing which specific property links ex:e1 to ex:e2.

Comment: "somehow" has to be an explicit relation either directly, or via a chain of relations.

Comment: In SPARQL, one can write something like `{?s a|!a ?o}` for "any relation".

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeking to express is that two resources are "somehow related". The best way to do this in RDF or OWL is to just model that relation explicitly (this is true of *all* relations in RDF/OWL):

```
ex:e1 ex:relatedTo ex:e2 .
```

It is exactly like any other relation. Note that in SKOS, by the way, an actual relation exists to model the "somehow related" relation: `skos:related`. This particular relation is not reusable outside SKOS though, because its domain and range are defined as `skos:Concept`. So just roll your own relation.

Alternatively, you can use a reified object to model the 'unknown relation':

```
# an unknown relation between e1 and e2 
ex:r1 a ex:UnknownRelation ;
      ex:subject ex:e1 ;
      ex:object ex:e2 .
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can say more things "about" the relation if you want, and also that while it captures the knowledge that a relation exists, it doesn't actually introduce a direct link between the two resources (which may or may not be what you want, depending on your use case). Of course a major downside is that it uses three triples to model a single relation, and it is harder to query through SPARQL. Whether it is worth it depends on your use case.